Factors affecting bond enthalpy
I am learning about chemical bonding and bond parameters, and came across this question:
Which of the following is the strongest bond?
a) C-C
b) C-H
c) C-N
d) C-O
I've learnt that bond enthalpy is influenced by these five factors:

Decreases when the size of atoms increases
Increases when the bond order increases
Increases when the s-character of the hybrid orbital increases
Decreases when the lone pair repulsion increases
Increases when the difference in electronegativity of the atoms
increases

On the basis of these five factors, how am I to find the strongest bond out of the four given ones?

C-H bond is $355$ (in propene) to $ 435$ kJ/mol (in methane); C-C bond is $348$ kJ/mol; C-N is $293$ kJ/mol; C-O is $360$ kJ/mol

@Maurice I assume OP asks rather about predictive qualitative reasoning than about hard quantitative data.
